# How to keep list view control on top of other window?

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I am working on a sample which contains list view to display list of names in the data base. Once the application is launched list view will be invisible. After clicking on some button I am making it to visible. If I make it to visible the control bellow the list view are also visible.  And I have button bellow that control, once I hove on the list view the button also displays over the list view.

Please let me now how to solve this problem.

Comment: Maybe is my problem, but I really can't figure out what the question is.

Comment: Yeah me too, if the OP still wants an answer, please rephrase.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have child windows on top of each other in a dialog. Use ShowWindow(SW_HIDE) to hide the windows that are 'underneath'. So when you make the listview visible, hide the button that is underneath.

On the windows desktop, application windows will properly hide other windows that are underneath one another, but in a dialog, different styles are used, and you have to be careful not to let controls overlap or they can draw on top of each other. Instead you need to hide the ones that you don't want to be visible.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, i thought of hiding the control. But for one of the button, half part is behind the list view. so i cant make it visible false. i don't know why buttons are coming up.